# Codeigniter : Sendmail cannot use Mailgun\Mailgun - it is not a trait Composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces

i try to sending email with library  [Mailgun](https://packagist.org/packages/mailgun/mailgun-php) install using composer in Codeigniter. I get some error with :

```
Fatal error: Sendmail cannot use Mailgun\Mailgun - it is not a trait in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngetest\application\controllers\Sendmail.php on line 4
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Sendmail cannot use Mailgun\Mailgun - it is not a trait

Filename: controllers/Sendmail.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:
```

I dont know why i'm get this error, i'm already follow documentation mailgun and watching youtube, but still get this error.

My configuration Codeigniter is :

#### My Sendmail Controller

```
<?php
class Sendmail extends CI_Controller
{
    use Mailgun\Mailgun;
    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
        # Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
        // require  FCPATH . './vendor/autoload.php';
    }
    public function index()
    {

        try {
            # Instantiate the client.
            $mgClient = new Mailgun('1xxxx');
            $domain = "xxx.mailgun.org";
            # Make the call to the client.
            $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
                'from'  => 'Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
                'to'    => 'Baz <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
                'subject' => 'Hello',
                'text'  => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
            ));
            return $result;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo ' $th';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed some of the info in your question as it was redundant or did not seem relevant to the issue, making the question difficult to read. Feel free to edit the question in case someone is asking for those details.

Comment: Thank's for edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your `use Mailgun\Mailgun;`. This must be at the beginning of the file, before you declare the class:

```php
<?php

use Mailgun\Mailgun;

class Sendmail extends CI_Controller
{
    ...
```

A `use` inside a class is treated differently, than one outside a class.

For reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: It's work after move `use Mailgun\Mailgun;` to top.